# compare an exact word with the txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to get the exact word match from my file along with their line no. 
like when i search for abc10 it gives me all the possible answers e.g abc102 abc103 etc
how can i limitize my code to only print what i commanded..

here is my code!

```
lineNo = 0

linesFound = []

inFile= open('rxmop.txt', 'r')

sKeyword = input("enter word ")
done = False

while not done :

    pos = inFile.tell()
    sLine = inFile.readline()
    if sLine == "" :
        done = True
        break

    if (sLine.find( sKeyword ) != -1):
        print ("Found at line: "+str(lineNo))
        tTuple = lineNo, pos
        linesFound.append( tTuple )
    lineNo = lineNo + 1
done = False
while not done :

    command = int( input("Enter the line you want to view: ") )

    if command == -1 :
        done = True
        break
    for tT in linesFound :
        if command == tT[0] :
            inFile.seek( tT[1] )
            lLine = inFile.readline()
            print ("The line at position " + str(tT[1]) + "is: " + lLine)
```

Comment: You don't need to set a flag *and* use `break`. One or the other is enough.

Comment: enter word RXOTG-10
Found at line: 5
Found at line: 167
Found at line: 185
Found at line: 203
Found at line: 221
Enter the line you want to view: 5
The line at position 147is: RXOTG-10          QTA5777                             HYB   SY    G12

Enter the line you want to view: 167
The line at position 6609is: RXOTG-100         QTA9278                             HYB   SY    G12

Enter the line you want to view: 

^my output from which i only like to see the contents of line 5

Answer (score 0):

"like when i search for abc10 it gives me all the possible answers e.g abc102 abc103 etc"

You split each record and compare whole "words" only.

```
to_find = "RXOTG-10"
list_of_possibles = ["RXOTG-10 QTA5777 HYB SY G12",
                     "RXOTG-100 QTA9278 HYB SY G12"]
for rec in list_of_possibles:
    words_list=rec.strip().split()
    if to_find in words_list:
        print "found", rec
    else:
        print "     NOT found", rec
```

Comment: my input is RXOTG-10 
and the outpt should only be 
line 5 
QTA5777 HYB SY G12 

nothing else where i m gettng more than six results for it

Comment: You have to split each record, as the code above does, and compare whole words only, as the code above does, which eliminates any other/extra characters included in the "found".  If you don't read and apply the answer then to answer further is a waste of time.

Comment: but the thing is that i have a huge file for placing in the list of possiblities that is why i am calling a file to work with it...in your answer you are taking possiblites as array (with only 2 entries)

Comment: Read each record one at a time (as you already do) and split and search each record one at a time (as the above code does -- it doesn't matter how many records there are).